# Laravel5.2 with count

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

I have the following problem, 
I have four models:
MainArea |Institute|institute_level|students with the following reations:

```
class MainArea extends Model
{
public function institute(){
 return $this->belongsTo('\App\Institute');     
}
public function places(){

    return $this->hasMany('\App\Place');
}
} 
class Institute extends Model
{
public function insLevel(){
    return $this->hasMany('\App\InstituteLevel');
}
}
class InstituteLevel extends Model
{
public function students(){
    return $this->hasMany('\App\Student','applying_level');
}
}
class Student extends Model
{
public function instituteLevel(){
    return $this->belongsTo('\App\InstituteLevel','institute_level_id');
}
public function place(){
    return $this->belongsTo('\App\Place');
}
}
```

Now, I want to get all areas with the count of students registered in it, in the same institute? it should be something like this.

```
        $areas=\App\MainArea::withCount('institute.insLevel.students')->where('institute_id',$id)->get();
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, "withCount()" doesn't support nested relationships as of Laravel 5.2.

[Here's the comment from the contributor in a Github Pull Request.](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/13414#issuecomment-227976494)